# Golang Equivalent for npm link

Tags: go

Using `npm link` in local development is very helpful when we're doing debugging on some packages.
You could just clone the repo into your local and then you can link them in your main app that consumes them.

What is the equivalent of `npm link` in Golang?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would recommend dep package manager.

Comment: @EddwinPaz Currently we're using go modules.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at `go mod vendor`. While it is not identical to npm link which creates a symbolic link to module, it provides a similar developer experience where dependencies are copied into `/vendor` directory of project similar `node_modules` of npm.

More documentation here: [Making vendored copies of dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Make_vendored_copy_of_dependencies)